# How do I set to zero lower triangles along the last two axes of a three-dimensional array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

I have a three-dimensional array with dimensions (N,M,M). I would like to set the diagonal and the lower triangle of each (M,M) array to zero. How to do it without looping along the first dimension? Is there a vectorized operation for that?

In just two dimensions (M,M) I would do

```
X = np.triu(X, k=1)
```

How do I generalize this into three dimensions without loops?

For example, input:

```
[[[ 1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6]
  [ 7  8  9]]

 [[10 11 12]
  [13 14 15]
  [16 17 18]]

 [[19 20 21]
  [22 23 24]
  [25 26 27]]

 [[28 29 30]
  [31 32 33]
  [34 35 36]]]
```

Expected output

```
[[[ 0  2  3]
  [ 0  0  6]
  [ 0  0  0]]

 [[0 11 12]
  [0 0 15]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 20 21]
  [0 0 24]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 29 30]
  [0 0 33]
  [0 0 0]]]
```

Comment: Could you give us a sample case with expected output for 3D?

Comment: Why do you impose the limitation of not using loops? If it is because of assumed performance issues, why not just use numba to JIT compile a simple implementation that is written with loops?

Comment: `X=np.ones((2,10,10))`

`X = np.triu(X, k=1)` works fine

Comment: @Brenlla That does appear to work, but it's unfortunate that the documentation for `triu` and `tril` explicitly says it expects the input to be two-dimensional, which means we probably need to look at the source code to be sure it's ok.

Comment: @ely. True [np.tril](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tril.html), should be documented better

Comment: Based on [the code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/twodim_base.py#L436) it does appear it should work. The call to `np.tri` is based only on the final two shape dimensions, and then the use of `where` will be broadcast along the first axis by the original shape.

Comment: @Divakar I edited the post, and added an example of expected output

Comment: ely, Brenlla, Thanks a lot! I checked, it works. I was really blinded by the documentation where it says that the input to triu should be 2-dim. A lesson for me: never fully trust docs, better test myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though not shown in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tril.html), `np.triu` supports broadcasting:

```
X=np.ones((2,10,10))
X=np.triu(X, k=1)
```

will give your desired results

Comment: Brenlla, Thanks a lot! I checked, it works. I was really blinded by the documentation where it says that the input to triu should be 2-dim. A lesson for me: never fully trust docs, better test myself